# Displaying and not displaying content in a table using angular

Tags: json, angularjs, webapi

I'm getting data from a JSON file and putting in a table and I want to display content based on a comparison otherwise leave it blank or some string but it display always both those who meet the comparison and not.

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-app ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax">
    <table class="table bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">Name</th>
                <th class="text-left">Status</th>
                <th class="text-left">Last Run</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
                <td>
                    {{post._Name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    
                    {{post.Status}}  
                </td>
               
                 <td>
                     <span ng-show="post.LastRun | date:'yyyy:dd:mm HH:mm:ss' > 1950:00:00 00:00:00 | date:'yyyy:dd:mm HH:mm:ss ">
                         {{post.LastRun | date:'yyyy:dd:mm HH:mm:ss'}}
                     </span>
                </td>
                 
            </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Could some one tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do this with some function in the PostsCtrlAjax controller that verifies the dates, it will perform faster and you can check some console output of the dates... 
and the comparison has to be

```
date1.getTime() === date2.getTime()
```